# Python Requests: Generating a specific token (__cf_bm)

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I recently got into using the requests library.

What I am doing: Posting a request to a url, parsing the response html for an element. Here is what my current code looks like:

```
import requests
client = requests.Session()
client.get(URL) #the url of the site
csrftoken = self.client.cookies["csrftoken"] # the payload requires the token
r = client.post(url=URL, data=dict(csrftoken=csrftoken, download=link)) 
for line in r.iter_lines():
  if b"id_to_be_located" in line:
    print(line)
```

I'm not getting the desired response. I did some digging are here is what I found out.

1. The response I get is of the original `URL` not the one that I'm supposed to get after the request.
2. Tried: `stream=True` and `allow_redirects=True` no luck. Cross-checking the post url, the payload
3. Finally I tried comparing the bare cookies of the python session and a browser session, turns out I have a cookie missing, namely `__cf_bm`.

Is there a way to generate that specific cookie? Obviously, I can try using selenium, but that's way too much of a small task. I don't know if I should be writing the name of the website, I'm open to questions and suggestions. Thanks

Comment: you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Add current code output and your desired out, then I will edit solution OK!

PS : findout your website web platform , some of them use specific name for csrftoken. For example django uses **X-CSRFToken** for cookies.

Comment: imo, the output of the code is irrelevant, but if you want it, the above code returns nothing, as there is no element `id_to_be_located`, bc as i told the post request returns the original `URL` instead of the new page. according to [this](https://builtwith.com), FRAMEWORKS: Django, CONTENT DELIVERY NETWORK: Cloudfare. If it was not clear, when I look up the cookies in a browser session, its has 2 `csrftoken` and `__cf_bm`, but the request session returns just one, `csrftoken`